# showing only one item per scroll-step, listbox, wpf

Tags: wpf, layout

I got a colection of quotes. The problem is that  I wan to be shown only one quote per scroll step. Ite meanst that user can not see more that one item in the laout panel, OK? Wrap panel does not slove my problem. Maybe something else?

Answer (score 1):

You could simply handle the scroll your self by handling the `ListBox`'s `PreviewMouseWheel` event:

```
 <ListBox PreviewMouseWheel="ListBoxScrollHandler" Width="200" Height="200" >
        <TextBlock Text="Quote 1"  Height="200"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Quote 2"  Height="200"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Quote 3"  Height="200"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Quote 4"  Height="200"/>     
    </ListBox>
```

and in the handler make sure one line is shown at a time by using `ScrollBar.LineDownCommand` or `ScrollBar.LineUpCommand` like this

```
   private void ListBoxScrollHandler(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Delta > 0)            
            ScrollBar.LineDownCommand.Execute(null, e.OriginalSource as IInputElement);            
        if (e.Delta < 0)            
            ScrollBar.LineUpCommand.Execute(null, e.OriginalSource as IInputElement);            
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

don't forget to add `using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;`